# Nesting Laravel applications (building a independed CMS)

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

I want to install a complete Laravel application in a subdirectory. This app will become a CMS which will run independed from the main app.

The reason for this is that the CMS will be used on multiple Laravel apps during the next years which will be based on multiple Laravel versions (5.2 and future versions).

The CMS will be used to maintain website content in a MySql database with fixed tables and fields. I know it is possible to create a package for such an app but then I have to maintain different versions of the CMS because they will run on different versions (older and future ones) of Laravel.

Is this good practice or will I run into unforseen problems when I nest Laravel apps this way?

Of course I already installed one in a subfolder and it seems to be working but are there specific things I have to take care of for this to work properly?

Comment: Laravel uses one project one application, i would suggest symfony3 since in project level which means one project many apps and many modules.

Comment: I do not want to switch to Symfony for this.